# exercise of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose that there exists $A > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \le A|z|^2$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$. If $f(1) = f(-1) = 1$, find a formula for $f(z)$.

**Attempt:**
Let $z \in \Bbb C$ and $R > 0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $C$ is a circle with equation $|w-z| = R$ with positive direction. Note that for all $w \in \Bbb C, w = z + Re^{i \theta}$ and that $dw = Rie^{i \theta} d\theta$.
Also, notice, by Cauchy Integral Formula, that
\begin{equation*}
f''(z) = \frac{2!}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^3} dw.
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
|f''(z)| &= \left|\frac{2!}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^3} Rie^{i \theta} d\theta \right| \\
&\le \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left| \frac{f(w) Re^{i \theta}}{(w-z)^3} \right| d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|f(w)|}{R^2} d\theta \\
&\le \frac{2\pi}{\pi} \left(\frac{A(z^2 + R^2)}{R^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{2A(z^2 + R^2)}{R^2},
\end{align*}
since $|f(w)| \le A|w|^2 = A(z^2 + R^2)$. Now, since $|f''(z)| \le \frac{2A(z^2 + R^2)}{R^2}$ is hold for all $R > 0$, then $f''(z) = 2$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$. Hence, $f'(z) = 2z + p$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$ and for some complex constant $p$. Therefore, $f(z) = z^2 + pz + q$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$ and fore some complex constants $p$ and $q$. Since $f(1)=f(-1)=1$, we have $p=q=0$ and thus, $f(z) = z^2$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

Am I correct?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is it $|f(z)| \le A|z|^n$ or $|f(z)| \le A|z|^2$?

Comment: @MartinR My bad. I mean, $|f(z)| \le A|z|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is a minor error ($A|w|^2 = A(z^2+R^2)$ is wrong) and some sloppiness (still using $w$ in the integral after the substitution $w = z + Re^{i \theta}$.
- The final conclusion does not work: From $|f''(z)| \le \frac{2A(z^2 + R^2)}{R^2}$ for sufficiently large $R$ you can only conclude that $|f''(z)| \le 2A$, but not $f''(z) = 2$.

If this is meant as an exercise for Liouville's theorem then you should consider the function $g(z) = f(z)/z^2$. Show that $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and apply Liouville's theorem to the extended function. It follows that $f(z) = c z^2$ for some constant $c$.

Using the Cauchy integral formulas is also possible, but then it is easier to estimate $f^{(n)}(0)$ for arbitrary $n$: Estimating the absolute value of
$$
f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i}\int_{|w|=R} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\, dw
$$
gives
$$
|f^{(n)}(0)| \le A n! R^{2-n}
$$
for all $R > 0$. Now consider the limits $R\to 0$ and $R \to \infty$ and conclude that $|f^{(n)}(0)| = 0$ if $n\ne 2$.

Comment: Why I should consider the function $g(z) = f(z) / z^2$ ?

Comment: Can I get the reference about it please ?

Comment: @alvarogonzales: Why? Because it works! Do you know Riemann's theorem on removable singularities?

Comment: Not yet. But I will read it later.

Comment: @MartinR apply Liouville's theorem to the extended function. It follows that..., how to apply it? which extended function ? $g(z)$ ?

Comment: @kuahmi: $g(z) = f(z)/z^2$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and has a removable singularity at $z=0$. $g$ can be extended to a function $G$ which is holomorphic in all of $\Bbb C$, and coincides with $g$ on $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Then Liouville's theorem is applied to $G$.

Comment: @MartinR the function $G$ is a piecewise function $G(z) = g(z), \ z \ne 0$ and $G(z) = 0, z = 0$ ?

Comment: @kuahmi: No, not necessarily. We only know that $G(0)$ can be defined in a way that the extended function is holomorphic. I suggest to have a look at [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).

Comment: Wait a second. $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. How can? Since $\lim_{z \to 0} zg(z) = f(z)/z \ne 0$ ?

Comment: @kuahmi: We know that $g$ is *bounded,* that is sufficient. You can find it all in Riemann's theorem.

Comment: @MartinR Aah I see. Since $g$ is bounded (by 1), then the limit is equal to 0 by Riemann's theorem. Like this?

Comment: @MartinR Define $G(z) = z^2 g(z)$ for $z \ne 0$ and $G(z) = 0$ for $z=0$. Then, $G(z) = f(z)$, by definition of $g$. Since $f$ is an entire function, then so is $G$, and hence $G$ is constant. Is it correct ?